# Isomorphisms of $GF(2)$

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, group-isomorphism

The additive group of $GF(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}2/\mathbb{Z}$
 under addition with the "carryless" addition taken modulo 2.

An appropriate relabelling of the elements ($0 \rightarrow 1$ and $1 \rightarrow -1$) maps the elements of $\mathbb{Z}2/\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{C}$ where addition corresponds to complex multiplication. This is an isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$.

Another isomorphism maps elements of $GF(2)$ to elements of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$, where addition becomes multiplication modulo 3 ($\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ having $\phi(3)=2$ elements).

- Are there any other, perhaps less-obvious, isomorphisms that I have not included?
- Are there any fully isomorphic mappings that facilitate both addition *and* multiplication in another structure?
- Why do isomprhisms like this exist?

I'm looking for reading material, so any mention of book titles would be very helpful.

Comment: This is too broad, there are many such isomorphisms. Also, the concept of a "one true" construction is meaningless.

Comment: Can you name any others in an answer?

Comment: Your "isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$" is not such a thing. What your construction *is* is an *injective* homomorphism to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^\times$, as well as an isomorphism with the multiplicative group of "complex square roots of $1$".

Answer (score 2):

Basically by construction, for any group $\mathbf{G}$, there is a natural bijective correspondence between:

- Group homomorphisms $\mathbf{Z} / 2 \mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{G}$
- $2$-torsion elements of $\mathbf{G}$

Furthermore, the homomorphism is monic if and only if the $2$-torsion element is not the identity.

So because lots of groups have 2-torsion elements, you find lots of homomorphisms from $\mathbf{Z} / 2 \mathbf{Z}$.